# Manage Document permission using SP Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library, designer-workflow, approval-process

I want to manage Document permission in document library using SharePoint Designer workflow like manage item level permission of list using workflow.

Can I manage permission of document using SharePoint Designer?

I got some [resources](http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html) to manage item level permission of list, but I want to manage document permission through workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workflow feature in the standard SP designer 2010 template (you have it if you are on sp 2010 or 13 or online, you do not have it if you are on SP 2007) called impersonation step.

This is one of the many pages that explain it

http://blogs.sharepoint911.com/blogs/jennifer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=91

If you google sharepoint workflow impersonation step you find more documentation.

Basically the workflow that starts automatically when a document is added will detach the single entity and attribute the permissions you want on it (certain people as editors or viewers or certain groups as sole editors etc).

Comment: Yup.. Thanks.. I got impersonation step. I was not aware of it. Thanks a lot dear for help..!!

Answer (score 0):

However, there is another way to handle your problem using a list and placing the document as attachment. This only if you do not need any feature on the document (versioning, approval etc).

This is a workaround if you want to avoid depending on a workflow. I have tested and if you send the link to a person that does not have rights to view the entry, even the attachment is access denied.